# Riemann integration of a piecewise function over $E=[0,1]\times [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration, iterated-integrals

> For the following, let $E=[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and let $S$ be the subset of $E$ defined by $$S=\{(x,y)\in E \ | \ x=\dfrac{2j+1}{2^n}, y=\dfrac{2k+1}{2^n}, j,k=0,...,2^{n-1}-1, n\in \mathbb{N}\}$$
>   Let $f:E\to R$ be defined by $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} 1, & (x,y)\in S \\ 0, & (x,y) \in E\backslash S
> \end{cases}$$
>
> (a) If it exists, compute $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y)dydx$. If it doesn't exist, explain why not.
>
> (b) If it exists, compute $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y)dxdy$. If it doesn't exist, explain why not.
>
> (c) Is $f$ Riemann integrable on $E$? Why or why not?

This is what I'm stuck on.  I'm thinking that if $x$ and $y$ as described are each dense in $[0,1]$, then both (a) and (b) are $1$; however, if this is the correct line of thinking, I'm unsure of how to go about showing it.  Also I have a gut feeling that (c) is no, but again I'm not sure how I'd show that.

Comment: the rationals are dense in $[0,1]$ but an indicator on those integrates to zero

Comment: The elements of $S$ are rational numbers, so the iterated integrals are zero. As for whether $f$ is integrable on $E$, you'll need to see whether $f$ is continuous at irrational numbers.

Comment: If they're dense in $[0,1]$, why do they integrate to zero and not one?